# JQ - group duplicates, not delete them

Tags: json, jq

I am trying to group the duplicates from the following json by `extId`, but remove duplicates.

(there are 2 'extId', I'm only interested in the one inside 'users')

**Here is the json:**

```
{
  "intId": "97210f2c23f45b55569f32309105f395c94",
  "extId": "39e9588ee62d1cccc711d75ff86c5570",
  "name": "generic name",
  "users": {
    "186-1": {
      "userKey": "186-1",
      "extId": "186",
      "intIds": {
        "w_eyvyfghz844o": {
          "intId": "w_eyvyfghz844o",
          "registeredOn": 1690289980777,
          "leftOn": 0,
          "userLeftFlag": false
        }
      },
      "name": "generic name 1",
      "isModerator": true,
      "isDialIn": false,
      "currentIntId": "w_eyvyfghz844o",
      "answers": {},
      "talk": {
        "totalTime": 5696194,
        "lastTalkStartedOn": 1690297856252
      },
      "emojis": [],
      "webcams": [
        {
          "startedOn": 1690289988531,
          "stoppedOn": 0
        }
      ],
      "totalOfMessages": 18
    },
    "95-1": {
      "userKey": "95-1",
      "extId": "95",
      "intIds": {
        "w_kegd1ecwju02": {
          "intId": "w_kegd1ecwju02",
          "registeredOn": 1690295357122,
          "leftOn": 1690295379924,
          "userLeftFlag": true
        },
        "w_nc1egwb2axbr": {
          "intId": "w_nc1egwb2axbr",
          "registeredOn": 1690296171797,
          "leftOn": 0,
          "userLeftFlag": false
        }
      },
      "name": "Generic name 2",
      "isModerator": true,
      "isDialIn": false,
      "currentIntId": "w_nc1egwb2axbr",
      "answers": {},
      "talk": {
        "totalTime": 0,
        "lastTalkStartedOn": 0
      },
      "emojis": [],
      "webcams": [],
      "totalOfMessages": 0
    },
    "95-2": {
      "userKey": "95-2",
      "extId": "95",
      "intIds": {
        "w_et8i4fc0fumu": {
          "intId": "w_et8i4fc0fumu",
          "registeredOn": 1690293905345,
          "leftOn": 1690294109923,
          "userLeftFlag": true
        }
      },
      "name": "Generic name 2",
      "isModerator": true,
      "isDialIn": false,
      "answers": {},
      "talk": {
        "totalTime": 0,
        "lastTalkStartedOn": 0
      },
      "emojis": [],
      "webcams": [],
      "totalOfMessages": 0
    }
  },
  "polls": {},
  "screenshares": [
    {
      "startedOn": 1690290408449,
      "stoppedOn": 1690290573091
    },
    {
      "startedOn": 1690294824305,
      "stoppedOn": 1690294957331
    },
    {
      "startedOn": 1690294976792,
      "stoppedOn": 1690295106468
    },
    {
      "startedOn": 1690295120270,
      "stoppedOn": 1690295742503
    },
    {
      "startedOn": 1690295747135,
      "stoppedOn": 1690297603487
    },
    {
      "startedOn": 1690297609337,
      "stoppedOn": 0
    }
  ],
  "presentationSlides": [
    {
      "presentationId": "8b8e93774c2cebfcde9582e0f9c169",
      "pageNum": 1,
      "setOn": 1690288860858
    }
  ],
  "createdOn": 1690288854908,
  "endedOn": 0
}
```

Here is what i have tried with:

```
jq -r '.users | [.[] | { "extId":(.extId),"name":.name, "conections":[( .intIds[] | {"registeredOn":.registeredOn,"leftOn":.leftOn,"userLeftFlag":.userLeftFlag} )] } ] | INDEX(.extId)'
```

```
{
  "186": {
    "extId": "186",
    "name": "generic name 1",
    "conections": [
      {
        "registeredOn": 1690289980777,
        "leftOn": 0,
        "userLeftFlag": false
      }
    ]
  },
  "95": {
    "extId": "95",
    "name": "Generic name 2",
    "conections": [
      {
        "registeredOn": 1690293905345,
        "leftOn": 1690294109923,
        "userLeftFlag": true
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

But using `INDEX(.extId)` removes the duplicates, so I understand that I need to group them before

```
[
  {
    "extId": "186",
    "name": "generic name 1",
    "conections": [
      {
        "registeredOn": 1690289980777,
        "leftOn": 0,
        "userLeftFlag": false
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "extId": "95",
    "name": "Generic name 2",
    "conections": [
      {
        "registeredOn": 1690295357122,
        "leftOn": 1690295379924,
        "userLeftFlag": true
      },
      {
        "registeredOn": 1690296171797,
        "leftOn": 0,
        "userLeftFlag": false
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "extId": "95",
    "name": "Generic name 2",
    "conections": [
      {
        "registeredOn": 1690293905345,
        "leftOn": 1690294109923,
        "userLeftFlag": true
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I don't require objects to have a key, but I would like to keep it.

Any help would be appreciated.

**Expected output:**

```
[
  "186": {
    "extId": "186",
    "name": "generic name 1",
    "connections": [
      {
        "registeredOn": 1690289980777,
        "leftOn": 0,
        "userLeftFlag": false
      }
    ]
  },
  "95": {
    "extId": "95",
    "name": "Generic name 2",
    "connections": [
      {
        "registeredOn": 1690295357122,
        "leftOn": 1690295379924,
        "userLeftFlag": true
      },
      {
        "registeredOn": 1690296171797,
        "leftOn": 0,
        "userLeftFlag": false
      },
      {
        "registeredOn": 1690293905345,
        "leftOn": 1690294109923,
        "userLeftFlag": true
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: What duplicates are you trying to remove?

Comment: @0stone0 I don't try to remove any duplicates, I try to group them

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood, please add desired output. Do you want the 2 `95` users to be in a single object, or an array holding those 2 users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to group by `.extId` while collecting the objects under `.intIDs[]`, then `group_by` has to go between the outer and the inner mappings:

```bash
.users
| map({extId, name, connections: .intIds | map({registeredOn, leftOn, userLeftFlag})})
| group_by(.extId)
| map(first + {connections: map(.connections[])})
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/MsceCe90UOr)

Alternatively, you could iterate using `reduce`, group manually on the go by collecting into an object, and restore the array using `map(.)`:

```bash
reduce .users[] as $user ({}; .[$user.extId] |= (($user | {extId, name}) + (
  .connections += [$user.intIds[] | {registeredOn, leftOn, userLeftFlag}]
))) | map(.)
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/BphcXi6bAeE)

Both approaches output

```json
[
  {
    "extId": "186",
    "name": "generic name 1",
    "connections": [
      {
        "registeredOn": 1690289980777,
        "leftOn": 0,
        "userLeftFlag": false
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "extId": "95",
    "name": "Generic name 2",
    "connections": [
      {
        "registeredOn": 1690295357122,
        "leftOn": 1690295379924,
        "userLeftFlag": true
      },
      {
        "registeredOn": 1690296171797,
        "leftOn": 0,
        "userLeftFlag": false
      },
      {
        "registeredOn": 1690293905345,
        "leftOn": 1690294109923,
        "userLeftFlag": true
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Thank you! The command with indices is left: ```jq '.users | map({extId, name, connections: .intIds | map({registeredOn, leftOn, userLeftFlag})}) | group_by(.extId) | map(first + {connections: map(.connections[])})  | INDEX(.extId)'``` . Could you say why it is better to use `group by` than `reduce`?

Comment: @ICIM If you want to keep the indices, just remove `| map(.)` from the second approach (the one using `reduce`). I also generally prefer `reduce` over filters like `group_by` or `INDEX` as they internally also iterate through the data themselves (mostly also using either `map` or `reduce`), so by chaining several of them you end up iterating multiple times. When writing your own `reduce`-based filter, you can often do things in parallel. But if your data set is small enough, the differences will probably hardly be noticeable, so in the end it doesn't really matter.